# Как вывести каждый массив типа char, в функции через указатели

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, char

Как вывести "Beta" используя функцию. В данный момент она выводит только "Alpha". Скорее всего что-то до глупости банальное, но я не допёр. Возможно указатели на указатели нужны (**), прошу доступно объяснить. В main вывод работает и выводит "Alpha" и "Beta".

```
#include <iostream>  
    
    using namespace std;                 
    
    int main()
    {
        void func(char*);
        
        char* arr[]={ "Alpha","Beta" };
        cout << *arr << endl;
        cout << *(arr+1) << endl;
        func(*arr);
        
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    
    void func(char* arrr)
    {
    
        cout << arrr << endl;
        
        
    }
```

Лучше использовать такой метод как я понял.

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;                 

int main()
{
    void func(char**, int);
    const int MAX = 2;
    char* arr[MAX]={ "Alpha","Beta" };
    
    func(arr, MAX);
    cout << *arr << endl;
    cout << *(arr + 1) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

  void func(char** arrr, int max) 
{
     
     for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
     {
         cout << *(arrr++) << endl;
     }
    
}
```

Comment: Так же, как и в `main`: `func(*(arr+1));` Только вот зря вы `const` забываете, ну неверно это — `char* arr[]={ "Alpha","Beta" };`, вы ж пытаетесь сделать изменяемым литерал...

Comment: Спасибо, я уже как только не пробовал, но не допер что нужно каждый массив отдельно передать в функцию. Был const, но я его вырезал для наглядности.

Comment: еще  получилось с указателями на указатели, сложно разобраться как работает, однако работает. Чтобы не передавать в функцию каждый раз указатель на отдельный массив, в этом как я понял и смысла нет, я передал просто arr без *.